# Are office365 font icons available for free use or for purchase?

Tags: css, sharepoint, fonts, office365, sharepoint-apps

I want to use the office365 font icons in a sharepoint app that i am developing, which will be deployed on office365.

If you have a look at the below image, you will find out in to right you can see the settings icon,
when I inspected it the span element has the class wf-family-0365 where the font family is 0365Icons.
Is there a way we can use it for free? Or purchase it?

[Link on forum](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/287747.aspx)
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal/commercial issues.

Comment: This is an old question, but one that I had. As mentioned above by Nitesh, these icons are part of the Office UI Fabric framework (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric). Microsoft recently released some documentation on how to use the framework at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/get-started#core. For example I just wanted to use the icon set, which was pretty easy to do - the "Get Started" page gives you the CSS link to use and then you can just refer to the icons page to get the correct name of the icons you want to use, FontAwesome-style.

Answer (score 3):

Recently Microsoft has released a front end framework known as **Office UI Fabric**. 
It's a responsive, mobile-first, front-end framework, designed to make it simple to quickly create web experiences using the Office Design Language. The styling takes into account typography, color, icons, animations, responsive grid layouts and localization. Fabric uses a custom font for its iconography. This font contains glyphs that we can scale, color, and style in any way. To use the icons, combine the base ms-Icon class with a modifier class for the specific icon. Eg: `<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--mail" ></i>` –

The cdn links given by @sjkp are broken now, you can find documentation with more details here>- [spo365icons.azurewebsites.net](http://spo365icons.azurewebsites.net)

The office fabric icons can be found http://dev.office.com/fabric/styles under the icons tab.

Comment: do you have working new link, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find them here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SPO365Icons";
    src: url("http://cdn.sharepointonline.com/15325/_layouts/15/fonts/Office365Icons.eot");
    src: url("http://cdn.sharepointonline.com/15325/_layouts/15/fonts/Office365Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url("http://cdn.sharepointonline.com/15325/_layouts/15/fonts/Office365Icons.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("http://cdn.sharepointonline.com/15325/_layouts/15/fonts/Office365Icons.ttf") format("truetype"), 
         url("http://cdn.sharepointonline.com/15325/_layouts/15/fonts/Office365Icons.svg#web") format("svg");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The gear specifically

```
.settings:before{
    font-family: SPO365Icons;
    content: "\e035";
}
```

Comment: He is asking if it's legal to use the icons in his app or not. Though your answer can be useful to someone but doesn't answer the question in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the icons are available for purchase. They are subject to license terms, as explained here:

http://officeuifabric.com/features/icons.html